# Missing END event for HTML5 Video element when video changes without page reload

Tags: javascript, youtube, html5-video, dom-events

I am using below code to detach the video events:

```
var HTML5VideoEvents = ["playing","pause","ended","seeked"];
var videos = win.document.getElementsByTagName("video");
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++){
  for (var j = 0; j < HTML5VideoEvents.length; j++){
    videos[i].addEventListener(HTML5Events[j], videoEvenDetected, false);
  }
}
```

This code  works fine In normal case and I get all the events, but when a different video is played without page reload for e.g. If I am watching one Youtube video and I click any other video from the right side bar list or If a next video in Amazon Prime. In both these case receive 'PLAYING' event for the next video and information related to next video curSRC, url etc.

Here just before the next video is played I want to know the previous video has been ENDED or SUSPENDED. Is there any way to do this. I tried to listen 'emptied' event also.

```
videos[i].addEventListener("emptied", detectVideoReset, false);
```

But above code doesn't work always. On Firefox and Safari video events for the next video are observed before reset event of previous video is detected. Also I need the info about previous video current time, url, curSRC, duration before the next video is started.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you have a look at the media element's load algorithm, which specifies the order in which media events are fired. As you indicated, the `emptied` event fires *after* `currentTime` and other variables are reset.... which makes sense, but is unfortunate for your use case.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/video.html#media-element-load-algorithm

Can you just log the `ended` event? If the event has been fired, mark the video as ENDED. Otherwise assume it has been SUSPENDED. You could also log the currentTime and src each time time the video has been paused - then use those values after `emptied` has been fired.

I would be curious to see if you find a more elegant solution...